# Howto validate image upload in PlayFramework 1?

Tags: java, image, validation, upload, playframework

I have to upload pictures with a few conditions :

- dimensions cannot exceed x pixels height, y pixels width,
- size cannot exceed *b* bytes on disk
- has to be a **PNG** or a **JPG** file
- has to be "resized"
- has to be saved to disk (using play's Blob)

Si far, I've found little to no information on image upload and/or check for Play!Framework. 
Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching a little in PlayFramework's source code, I've stumbled upon [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) ibrary already used in Play. Cannot understand, why such easy checks have not been added to the core library...

Here's the check part, I've created for :

- dimension check,
- type check,
- size check.

  ```
  package validators;

  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

  import play.Logger;
  import play.data.validation.Check;
  import play.db.jpa.Blob;
  import play.i18n.Messages;

  public class ImageValidator extends Check {

    public final static int MAX_SIZE = 4048;
    public final static int MAX_HEIGHT = 1920;

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object parent, Object image) {

      if (!(image instanceof Blob)) {
          return false;
      }

      if (!((Blob) image).type().equals("image/jpeg") && !((Blob) image).type().equals("image/png")) {
          return false;
      }

      // size check
      if (((Blob) image).getFile().getLength() > MAX_SIZE) {
          return false;
      }


      try {
          BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(((Blob) image).getFile());
          int width = source.getWidth();
          int height = source.getHeight();

          if (width > MAX_WIDTH || height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
              return false;
          }
      } catch (IOException exption) {
          return false;
      }


      return true;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom check, here's a sample from Play's documentation:

```
public class User {

    @Required
    @CheckWith(MyPasswordCheck.class)
    public String password;

    static class MyPasswordCheck extends Check {

        public boolean isSatisfied(Object user, Object password) {
            return notMatchPreviousPasswords(password);
        }

    }
}
```

And here's a link to great post from Lunatech on file uploading with Play:
http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob

Comment: I have seen both posts. Before posting here, I've done a little research, you know. ;) Plus, my question is clearly oriented toward "image" upload validation and none of those two, answers my question in any way.